# while we selecting an image link with link text/ href/xpath it gives error Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium

while we selecting an image link with link  text/ href/xpath  it gives error Message: no such element: Unable to locate element.in the webpage only one link text existed with that name still we are not able to click that link text[image]

[image]

```
<frameset rows=" 20%, *,4%" border="0">
    <frame name="1" src="headerForm.do" scrolling="auto" noresize="noresize">
    <frameset cols="20%,*" border="0">
        <frame src="menuForm.do" scrolling="auto" noresize="noresize">
        <frame src="welcome.do" name="Main" scrolling="auto" noresize="noresize">
    </frameset>
    <frame name="3" src="footerForm.do" scrolling="auto" noresize="noresize">
</frameset>
```

Comment: The think the Element you are trying to locate is in an `iframe`. Have switched to `iframe` and tried to locate that element?

Comment: <frame src="menuForm.do" scrolling="auto" noresize="noresize"> this is the webelement how can we switch iframe here

Comment: Try to use the index of the frame. `driver.switch_to.frame(0)` if its the 1st iframe.

Comment: <frameset rows=" 20%, *,4%" border="0">
        <frame name="1" src="headerForm.do" scrolling="auto" noresize="noresize">
        <frameset cols="20%,*" border="0">
            <frame src="menuForm.do" scrolling="auto" noresize="noresize">
            <frame src="welcome.do" name="Main" scrolling="auto" noresize="noresize">
        </frameset>
        <frame name="3" src="footerForm.do" scrolling="auto" noresize="noresize">
    </frameset>
this is the frame can you suggest correct way to select it

Comment: @Chitradaadikrishna : I could answer this question, but I see that you do not accept the answers, so sorry !